# In a SAS `X` command, how can I pass carriage return?

Tags: loops, unix, sas

I am trying to submit something like below so that I can copy all datasets in a directory to another directory, but prefixed with an identifier `ID1`:

```
for name in *.sas7bdat
do
        cp "$name" "ID1$name"
done
```

I've tried using many variations but not luck so far - a few examples are:

```
x 'for name in *.sas7bdat' ;
x 'do';
x 'cp "$name" "ID1$name"' ;
x 'done' ;

x 'for name in *.sas7bdat' 'OD'x 'do' 'OD'x 'cp "$name" "ID1$name"' 'OD'x 'done' ;
x 'for name in *.sas7bdat'       'do'       'cp "$name" "ID1$name"' '     'done' ;
x 'for name in *.sas7bdat' \n    'do' \n    'cp "$name" "ID1$name"' \n    'done' ;
```

Comment: What scripting language? Perhaps easier to write that script to a file and then use X statement to call it?  What command do you type at a shell prompt to get this loop to work?  If you can type it at a shell prompt, should be able to get x command to execute it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just write the bash script (for... do... done...) in a single line and run the x command on it.

```
x 'for name in *.sas7bdat; do; cp "$name" "ID1$name"; done';
```

Another option would be store the entire for loop in a single file, ensure it is executable (chmod +x filename) and then execute the file as a script using the x command.

A few bash examples here - http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-bash-for-loop-one-line-command/

Comment: Also see [the SAS documentation](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/hostunx/61879/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000290413.htm) which specifically shows an example of using `;` to separate commands.